# Regarding intents and putExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent

Im having some doubts with this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"; 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); 
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); 
    String message = editText.getText().toString(); 
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

1. Why we are using casting in EditText
2. What is putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message) and its use??
3. Why is MY_MESSAGE assigned to com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE? and What is com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE?

Comment: Maybe you should consider reading the Docs. These are very basic question that can be answered easily by googling the doc of the method. Will also give you some more background input :) Peace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Because `findViewById()` is a generic method which returns a View

2) An intent is a flexible way for decoupled communication, it's like a message that you send (specifying a desired action and optional extra data). `putExtra()` is a method that allows you to embed information into your intent

3) Intent's extra data is based on a key-value storage. EXTRA_MESSAGE is the key where your message is stored. The receiver of your intent knows that it can retrieve your message from this key.

4) "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE" is the actual value of this key. It's an arbitrary value which has to be known by the sender of the intent and its receiver so that they communicate through the intent

Answer (score 0):

intent extras are used to pass data parametres to others  activitys, so if you want to launch a new activity and you want to pass a string to the new activity you should add extra string to your intent as in you example : EXTRA_MESSAGE is the key and message si the message

Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Parameters
name  The name of the extra data, with package prefix. 
value  The String data value.

Returns
Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls into a single statement.